# How can vinyl chloride arise from treating 1,2-dichloroethane with a solution of potassium hydroxide in ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Liebig apparently created it that way (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_chloride#Production). However, googling I can not find chemical equation for such reaction, I only see ethene as result of such elimination reaction:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-product-when-1-2-dichloroethane-reacts-with-alcoholic-KOH

Comment: The Quora answer is wrong. Vinyl chloride arises from the elimination of one eq of HCl from dichloroethane. Push it harder and you get ethyne.

Comment: I get it, thanks. Is the result then Vinil chloride + potassium chloride + water?

Comment: Correct. Vinyl chloride, water and KCl